# Creating the object of a foreign or onetoone field from the model linked to it in the form?

Tags: django

Example model :

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOnefield(User)
    name=models.Charfield()
    phone=models.IntegerField()
```

Now in forms.py, I want to signup with all the above information. How can we nest the foreign or onetoone field so we can create user.

Comment: what have you tried? Show us your `forms.py`

Comment: start coding if you stack . then ask

Comment: Override init and save methods to handle user?